# I have a code or stop the loop, I do not know how I can do for what stops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code or stop the loop, I do not know how I can do for what stops

```
ciao = "revoir bye see you"
ciao = ciao.lower().split()
quests = "revoir mam bak kio"
quests = quests.lower().split()
while 1: 
    for i in range(len(quests)):
        if quests[i] in ciao:
            break
        print('khvb')
```

Comment: Sorry, what? I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear.

The break will only stop the for loop, if you want it to stop the while loop, you might consider something like this:

```py
ciao = "revoir bye see you"
ciao = ciao.lower().split()
quests = "revoir mam bak kio"
quests = quests.lower().split()
should_continue = True
while should_continue: 
    for i in range(len(quests)):
        if quests[i] in ciao:
            should_continue = False
            break
        print('khvb')
``
```